# output of strtok() is different

Tags: c, strtok

I want to compare two strings which contains some other characters as well. To eliminate those characters I am using strtok()

First I am copying strings into temp buffers, which I will use in strtok().

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {
            char ch[50]="supl-dev.google.com";
            char ch1[50]="*.google.com";
            printf("ch =%s\n",ch);
            printf("ch1 =%s\n",ch1);
            char temp_ch[50], temp_ch1[50];
            strcpy(temp_ch,ch);
            strcpy(temp_ch1,ch1);
            char *ch_token, *ch1_token;

            ch_token = strtok(temp_ch,".");
            ch1_token = strtok(temp_ch1,"*");
            printf("ch_token=%s\n",ch_token);
            printf("ch1_token = %s\n",ch1_token);
       
            return 0;
    }
```

Expected results :

> ch =supl-dev.google.com
>
> ch1 =*.google.com
>
> ch_token=supl-dev
>
> ch1_token = *

Actual results :

> ch =supl-dev.google.com
>
> ch1 =*.google.com
>
> ch_token=supl-dev
>
> ch1_token = .google.com

Here I am expecting ch1_token should contain '*'.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Your expectation is wrong. You set your delimiter for `ch2` to `*`, which means that `strtok` will strip off the leading `*` in `*.google.com` and return `.google.com` as the first token. To get what you want, you have to set the delimiter to `.`.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        char ch[50]="supl-dev.google.com";
        char ch1[50]="*.google.com";
        printf("ch =%s\n",ch);
        printf("ch1 =%s\n",ch1);
        char temp_ch[50], temp_ch1[50];
        strcpy(temp_ch,ch);
        strcpy(temp_ch1,ch1);
        char *ch_token, *ch1_token;

        ch_token = strtok(temp_ch,".");
        ch1_token = strtok(temp_ch1,".");
        printf("ch_token=%s\n",ch_token);
        printf("ch1_token = %s\n",ch1_token);

        return 0;
}
```

Now `ch_token` should be `supl-dev` and `ch1_token` should be `*`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind is that `strtok` will go on to find the next token if the current token is empty.

So, when you `strtok` the string `*.google.com` with delimiter `*`, it finds the delimiter in the first position itself. As the current token is empty, the next token is returned which is `.google.com`

Answer (score 1):

you are splitting the `ch1` by `*` so its result is an empty string which is ignored and the rest of string which is `.google.com`.(it ignores `*` because it's your delimiter).
just change your splitting code to `ch1_token = strtok(temp_ch1,".");` and it will return `*`,`google` and then `com`.

Comment: Thank you, Here I want to get rid of '*' and want to use rest of the string (.google.com) for next steps.

Comment: @Saawaj after getting `*` you can use `ch1_token = strtok(NULL, '.');`. result should be: ch1_token = "google"

Comment: and repeating this sentence will get you `com`

Answer (score 0):

Your stated need is to search for a common sub-string within two strings.
Using `strtok` may work, but there are simpler ways to do this without parsing.

Have you considered using *[strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)]*?

```
    char ch[50]="supl-dev.google.com";
    char ch1[50]="*.google.com";
    if((strstr(ch, "google.com")) && (strstr(ch1, "google.com"))
    {
        /// sub-string exists in both strings
    }
```

Comment: Actually to explain problem easily I stated that but actually, I want to compare strings  which contains some wild characters and there are some conditions which should met to define it SUCCESS case.

Comment: @Saawaj - What are those conditions in your problem statement that define SUCCESS case?  It is not clear from reading your main post.